# Sending one copy of each CiviMail campaign to a specific email address?

Tags: civimail, sparkpost

I have been asked to generate one copy of each mailing sent to go to a specific mailbox (say emails@example.org) that they will check for validation of emails sent (with content comparison) versus emails requested to be sent (with content requests).

I have proposed a group with just "emails@example.org" in it which gets put into the recipients for each civiMail we send out for lack of a better solution in my mind, but have been told that is unacceptable and it must be automatic.

I don't believe I can simply put "emails@" in every mailing group either because I will have no way of necessarily knowing if a new mailing group is created to add this email address to.

We are using civiCRM 4.6.4 and Drupal 7.43 and using Sparkpost as our mail service. I have thought a bit about forwarding in Sparkpost but I haven't thought of a way not to forward a number of copies of each email equal to the number of targets to our verifying inbox.

Has anyone set something like this up using civiMail? Or have any ideas how I might go about this?

Answer (score 1):

CiviRules provides a good foundation for say 'if trigger X happens, then do Action Y'.

I have no idea if the option you need is there but if it isn't it might be a good place to add it.

In other words, create a rule that says, if a Group is created then add contact X to it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This may take me awhile to test out and respond because we don't have CiviRules installed yet and I may need to learn to add a new rule following the (rather complex for me) documentation I have found: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviRules+-+how+to+make+your+own. I'll let you know how it goes!